# mapping enum on ibatis

Tags: java, enums, mapping, ibatis

I have an enum something like this

```
public Enum MyEnum { 
  NEW("NEW"),
  OLD("OLD"),
  IN_PROCESS("IN PROCESS");
}
```

The mapping on ibatis works fine for the **NEW** and **OLD**, but encounters an error when the **IN_PROCESS** is encountered since the value of my **IN_PROCESS** in the DB is **IN PROCESS**, and the error indicates that ibatis tries to find an enum with that value, can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyBatis use an [EnumTypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/EnumTypeHandler.java) to do mappings with enums. In this Enum type handler it uses the `name()` method of the Enums which returns the string value of the variable name. 
For example NEW -> "NEW" and IN_PROCESS -> "IN_PROCESS".

Otherwise, to get the value it uses `Enum.valueOf(type, s);` which gets the value of the Enum through the String value which corresponds with the variable name ("NEW" -> MyEnum.NEW, "IN_PROCESS" -> MyEnum.IN_PROCESS) and internally is used the method `name()`.

You cannot overwrite `name()` because is marked as final so you options are:

1. The easy way is to use IN_PROCESS instead of IN PROCESS. I prefer this, is easier and fast.
2. The second option is create your TypeHanlder for this enum and check if the `parameter` is IN PROCESS and search with IN_PROCESS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I ended up writing a custom setter on my POJO to convert the string value.

```
public Enum MyEnum { 
  NEW("NEW"),
  OLD("OLD"),
  IN_PROCESS("IN PROCESS");

  public static MyEnum fromValue(String v){
     .... find the enum based on value 
  }
}

public class POJO {
   private   MyEnum myEnum;
   public void setMyEnum(String strV){
        myEnum=MyEnum.fromValue(strV)
    }
}
```